# How to load Image?

Tags: java, 3d

I want load an image for set to a texture but it has error.
it trowed an exception.
please help me.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Texture:illegal image size
    at javax.media.j3d.TextureRetained.checkImageSize(TextureRetained.java:419)
    at javax.media.j3d.TextureRetained.initImage(TextureRetained.java:364)
    at javax.media.j3d.Texture.setImage(Texture.java:959)
    at javaapplication1.Draw.Creat(Draw.java:63)
    at javaapplication1.Draw.<init>(Draw.java:30)
    at javaapplication1.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

***edit***

I check that my image size was 128 * 128.
if this true?
my image format is *.jpg

this is my code.

```
public class Draw extends Applet{

public Draw() {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("1.jpg"));

    } catch (Exception e) {


    }
    TextureLoader loader = new TextureLoader(image, "RGB",
            TextureLoader.ALLOW_NON_POWER_OF_TWO);
    ImageComponent2D icd = loader.getImage();
    Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D();
    texture2D.setImage(0, icd);
}
```

Comment: You have asked 10 Questions. are you sure you haven't been asnwered ?

Comment: I am no expert but maybe it has something to do with the image size. "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Texture:illegal image size"

Comment: javadoc is your friend....  A quick googling of the Texture class yields javadoc that explains the size requirements for setImage.

Answer (score 0):

Look up TextureLoader in the API.